# Connecting "C" wire Gas Furnace

Tags: hvac

Have spent hours searching for answer for my application to no avail.
I am  going to install a Honeywell  RTH9580wf. These pics pic show my current 4 wire setup. I  have run a new 5 wire line and would like verification on where to connect the "C" wire at Furnace and New T Stat. The "C" wire  would be Yellow if I leave things as they currently are. Thanks...

[image]
  [image]
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Comment: Is this a trick question? There's a terminal labeled `C` right in the picture.

Comment: I didn't intend it to be... I just have enough knowledge to be dangerous. So the answer is that simple?

Comment: without seeing a schematic, I can't say with 100% certainty.  However, everything about the wiring suggests that the terminal labeled C is the `C` terminal.

Comment: Pic of schematic added. Thanks for your time. Furnace is 1990 Amana Air Command 80.

Comment: Thanks for diagram. One other concern I have, is the ability of the transformer to adequately power the new thermostat as well as the humidifier which is connected to the terminals on top of transformer.

Comment: can't say for sure without knowing the VA rating of the transformer, and the current draw of all the equipment it's powering.

Comment: Transformer looks like 12VA rated. Sounds kind of low to me...

Comment: 12 is low. They're usually 40-60VA, especially when also powering a humidifier.

Answer (score 1):

According to the schematic, the labeled `C` terminal is the `C` terminal.

[image]